# Prove that for a real, normal square matrix A, R^n = R(A) + N(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I was given this as a homework question, and I've already turned in the assignment with the second part unanswered..  any help would be great!

Matrices with the property `A*A = AA*`are said to be normal.

1. Prove that if A is normal, then R(A) ⊥ N(A), i.e. if x ∈ R(A) and y ∈ N(A), then x*y = 0.

This was simple enough to prove.  We know

```
    R(A) = R(AA*)

    N(A) = N(A*A)

    A*A = AA*
```

So,
 `x ∈ R(A) = R(AA*)   ⇒   x = AA*z for some z   ⇒   x* = z*AA*`

and
`y ∈ N(A) = N(A*A) ⇒  A*Ay = 0`

Then, 
`<x,y> = x*y`
`= z*(AA*)y`
`= z*(A*A)y`
`= z*(0)`
`= 0`
  `Therefore x*y = 0 is true.`

This second part of the question is what's I'm confused on -

If a real n x n matrix A is normal `(A*A = AA*)`, is it true that R<sup>n</sup> = R(A) + N(A)? Justify your answer.

I know that it is true, but I don't understand why or how to prove it.
If you could explain it in layman's terms, that would be great!  Like I said, the above proof was easy enough.. but I don't have a strong fundamental understanding of the material at this point (though I would like to!).

Answer (score 2):

This fact follows from two subfacts:

(a) $N(T^*) = R(T)^\perp$ for any matrix $T$.

(b) $N(A) = N(A^*)$ for normal $A$.

For (a) we have $x\in N(T^*)$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $T^*x = 0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\langle T^*x,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\langle x,Ty\rangle = 0$ for all $y$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x\in R(T)^\perp$.

For (b) let $x\in N(A)$. Then $\|A^*x\|^2= \langle A^*x,A^*x\rangle = \langle AA^*x,x\rangle = \langle A^*Ax,x\rangle = 0$. Hence $N(A)\subset N(A^*)$. As also $A^*$ is normal, it holds that $N(A^*)\subset N(A^{**})= N(A)$.

So, in your case you get $R(A)^\perp = N(A^*) = N(A)$ and thus $\mathbb R^n = R(A)\oplus N(A)$.